# TLP turned off the OS's ability to show available wireless connections

Tags: networking, power-management, battery

Hello I just installed tlp and when the battery got low, wifi was stopped. 
So I connected the power adapter. And I got the wifi back. 
Immediately I have changed the value of WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT to off in the tlp config. 
But I am no more able to see the list of available wifi connections.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I faced this same issue on a different computer in older version of ubuntu.

Here is the pastebin link for the wireless script output: http://pastebin.com/xcm7YA8w

Kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks. That worked. This should be an answer probably. Linux is weird as hell. smh..

Comment: If that solved your problems, kindly vote on the answers as an appreciate for the answerer. Thanks.

Comment: @WafieAli When I click upvote, it shows me this message: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Comment: I see. sorry for my forgot. thanks for remind me.

Answer (score 1):

The wireless adapter seems to be working alright and it appears it was just NetworkManager that doesn't deal well with TLP's shenanigans.

Restarting NetworkManager fixed the issue:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

Comment: I think I spoke too soon. The solution wasn't a permanent one. If I restart my PC, the problem reappears again.

Comment: Yes, that's what I expected. This only recovers from the situation described in your question but it doesn't prevent it. Didn't you say you configured TLP to not shut down wireless networking?

Comment: Yeah. I have set the WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT to off in tlp config. I figured out that the problem is unrelated to tlp. I did a fresh install and still had the problem. 
It has to do with the "login automatically". During installation, I have selected login automatically. I noticed when I was logging out and logging in for switching graphics card, the issue was fixing itself.

So I have disabled the automatic login in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf by commenting out autologin-user=code_brah and autologin-user-timeout=0 and the issue fixed itself. Not sure why though.

Comment: Sounds like that might be a bug.